# Local Path doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating Android Studio to 0.4.5, I cannot get my application to build. I have the following configurations:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportMode true
```

NOTE: Cleaning + Rebuilding the project, deleting .iml/idea files and reimporting the project, setting APK_PATH, and/or syncing files with gradle does NOT fix this issue.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: What is classpath inside dependencies? Are you sure about your gradle script?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `<projectName>.iml` After updating Android Studio that error might occur but you can fix it updating the `<projectName>`.iml file adding this snippet:

```
<facet type="android" name="Android">
<configuration>
 <option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/<projectName>-debug-unaligned.apk" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
./gradlew clean packageDebug --debug
```

fixed the error.