# android studio1.0.2 Local path doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

My English is not good :),sorry.

I am use studio to build Android Contacts apk, include Contacts, ContactsCommon(lib) and PhoneCommon().

now , when i run app , Local path doesn't exist.

Android SDK Tools 24.0.2 (newest)

build.gradle(project)

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

gradle-wrapper.properties

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

I am try to follow methods:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/27436269/4397112

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21842216/4397112

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667599/4397112

etc..

in my project's root directory, run:

> gradlew clean packageDebug
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>   >         D:\Development\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat -JXmx4g --dex --output D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Contacts\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-jarjar_framework-5c27d5f8ec6e579f128703ae9232253b06c7d5
>   >     2e.jar
>   >     D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Contacts\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Contacts\ContactsCommon\unspecified\libs\classes-jarjar_framework.jar
>   >     Error Code:
>   >         2 Output:
>
>   ```
>   trouble writing output: Too many method references: 81922; max is 65536.
>   You may try using --multi-dex option.
>   References by package:
>       27 android
>      147 android.accessibilityservice
>      577 android.accounts
>       33 android.alsa
>      682 android.animation
>       11 android.annotation
>     5500 android.app
>      542 android.app.admin
>      401 android.app.backup
>      140 android.app.job
>       53 android.app.trust
>       89 android.app.usage
>      134 android.appwidget
>     1750 android.bluetooth
>      222 android.bluetooth.le
>     1879 android.content
>     1537 android.content.pm
>      554 android.content.res
>      532 android.database
>      498 android.database.sqlite
>      117 android.ddm
>      168 android.drm
>       30 android.emoji
>       23 android.filterfw
>      817 android.filterfw.core
>       26 android.filterfw.format
>       42 android.filterfw.geometry
>       46 android.filterfw.io
>       83 android.filterpacks.base
>      410 android.filterpacks.imageproc
>        6 android.filterpacks.numeric
>       17 android.filterpacks.performance
>       18 android.filterpacks.text
>       29 android.filterpacks.ui
>       18 android.filterpacks.videoproc
>       21 android.filterpacks.videosink
>       86 android.filterpacks.videosrc
>      223 android.gesture
>     1458 android.graphics
>     1337 android.graphics.drawable
>       40 android.graphics.drawable.shapes
>       87 android.graphics.pdf
>      532 android.hardware
>      283 android.hardware.camera2
>       19 android.hardware.camera2.dispatch
>      339 android.hardware.camera2.impl
>      462 android.hardware.camera2.legacy
>       25 android.hardware.camera2.marshal
>      213 android.hardware.camera2.marshal.impl
>      137 android.hardware.camera2.params
>      153 android.hardware.camera2.utils
>      247 android.hardware.display
>      431 android.hardware.hdmi
>      167 android.hardware.input
>      388 android.hardware.location
>      174 android.hardware.soundtrigger
>      231 android.hardware.usb
>      442 android.inputmethodservice
>     1053 android.location
>     3957 android.media
>      293 android.media.audiofx
>       44 android.media.audiopolicy
>       82 android.media.browse
>       48 android.media.effect
>       39 android.media.effect.effects
>      141 android.media.projection
>      645 android.media.session
>      964 android.media.tv
>      144 android.mtp
>     2232 android.net
>      102 android.net.dhcp
>      408 android.net.http
>      106 android.net.nsd
>      819 android.net.wifi
>      250 android.net.wifi.p2p
>       96 android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd
>        1 android.net.wimax
>      455 android.nfc
>       73 android.nfc.cardemulation
>      175 android.nfc.tech
>     1728 android.opengl
>     2778 android.os
>      266 android.os.storage
>      874 android.preference
>      655 android.print
>        6 android.print.pdf
>      169 android.printservice
>      631 android.provider
>     1854 android.renderscript
>       35 android.sax
>      272 android.security
>      160 android.service.dreams
>       76 android.service.fingerprint
>       85 android.service.media
>      275 android.service.notification
>       39 android.service.persistentdata
>        3 android.service.restrictions
>       30 android.service.textservice
>       70 android.service.trust
>      199 android.service.voice
>      137 android.service.wallpaper
>      149 android.speech
>      133 android.speech.srec
>      579 android.speech.tts
>       32 android.system
>     1010 android.telecom
>      958 android.telephony
>       48 android.telephony.cdma
>       14 android.telephony.gsm
>       52 android.test
>      812 android.text
>      116 android.text.format
>      374 android.text.method
>      375 android.text.style
>       49 android.text.util
>      556 android.transition
>      922 android.util
>     5239 android.view
>      591 android.view.accessibility
>      274 android.view.animation
>      473 android.view.inputmethod
>      139 android.view.textservice
>      934 android.webkit
>     8709 android.widget
>       19 com.android.i18n.phonenumbers
>        2 com.android.i18n.phonenumbers.geocoding
>      111 com.android.ims
>      469 com.android.ims.internal
>       24 com.android.internal
>        7 com.android.internal.annotations
>     1298 com.android.internal.app
>       98 com.android.internal.appwidget
>      130 com.android.internal.backup
>       92 com.android.internal.content
>       23 com.android.internal.database
>        8 com.android.internal.http
>       78 com.android.internal.http.multipart
>      106 com.android.internal.inputmethod
>       78 com.android.internal.location
>       12 com.android.internal.logging
>       51 com.android.internal.net
>      961 com.android.internal.os
>       23 com.android.internal.os.storage
>      156 com.android.internal.policy
>       27 com.android.internal.preference
>      184 com.android.internal.statusbar
>      403 com.android.internal.telecom
>      969 com.android.internal.telephony
>       94 com.android.internal.textservice
>        3 com.android.internal.transition
>      632 com.android.internal.util
>      499 com.android.internal.view
>       17 com.android.internal.view.animation
>      616 com.android.internal.view.menu
>     1723 com.android.internal.widget
>      232 com.android.internal.widget.multiwaveview
>       42 com.android.net
>       20 com.android.okhttp
>        3 com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509
>        2 com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.encoders
>        9 com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem
>        9 com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509
>       28 com.android.org.conscrypt
>       69 com.android.server
>        9 com.android.server.backup
>       31 com.android.server.net
>       13 com.google.android.collect
>      313 com.google.android.gles_jni
>      170 com.google.android.util
>        1 dalvik.bytecode
>       75 dalvik.system
>        7 dalvik.system.profiler
>        5 default
>      241 java.io
>      461 java.lang
>        5 java.lang.ref
>       39 java.lang.reflect
>        2 java.math
>      100 java.net
>      118 java.nio
>        7 java.nio.channels
>       15 java.nio.charset
>       40 java.security
>       16 java.security.cert
>        7 java.security.spec
>       43 java.text
>      437 java.util
>       52 java.util.concurrent
>       19 java.util.concurrent.atomic
>       21 java.util.concurrent.locks
>        6 java.util.jar
>       13 java.util.logging
>       16 java.util.regex
>       29 java.util.zip
>        8 javax.crypto
>        2 javax.crypto.spec
>       33 javax.microedition.khronos.egl
>      267 javax.microedition.khronos.opengles
>        1 javax.net
>       27 javax.net.ssl
>        8 junit.framework
>        7 libcore.icu
>        2 libcore.internal
>       18 libcore.io
>        5 libcore.net
>        2 libcore.net.event
>       29 libcore.util
>        2 org.apache.commons.codec.binary
>        4 org.apache.commons.logging
>       16 org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc
>        2 org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util
>        2 org.apache.harmony.security.asn1
>        6 org.apache.harmony.security.pkcs7
>        1 org.apache.harmony.security.x509
>        1 org.apache.harmony.xml
>       30 org.apache.http
>       10 org.apache.http.client
>        4 org.apache.http.client.methods
>        1 org.apache.http.client.params
>        1 org.apache.http.conn
>        4 org.apache.http.conn.scheme
>        1 org.apache.http.conn.ssl
>       10 org.apache.http.entity
>        3 org.apache.http.impl
>        3 org.apache.http.impl.client
>        1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm
>        3 org.apache.http.impl.entity
>        6 org.apache.http.impl.io
>        6 org.apache.http.io
>       12 org.apache.http.message
>       13 org.apache.http.params
>        9 org.apache.http.protocol
>       11 org.apache.http.util
>        3 org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup
>        2 org.kxml2.io
>       13 org.xml.sax
>        1 org.xml.sax.helpers
>       34 org.xmlpull.v1
>   ```
> - Try:         Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>                BUILD FAILED
>                Total time: 1 mins 34.902 secs

I guess maybe classes-jarjar_framework.jar too big. i am building android source now, i will find some jar instead of classes-jarjar_framework.jar tomorrow.

someone give some advice, thanks very much

**update 12/28 2014**

thank @stkent, finally, i use https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle To solve my problem. i love stack overflow.

when you encounter "Local path doesn't exist" problem, first you should know where is problem.
so run

> gradlew clean packageDebug

no --Debug , less infomation

next, solve it

My english is not good, sorry again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app has reached the 65K methods limit. See [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) for solutions. Copied from the documentation:

> Avoiding the 65K Limit
>
> Before configuring your app to enable use of 65K or more method references, you should take steps to reduce the total number of references called by your app code, including methods defined by your app code or included libraries. The following strategies can help you avoid hitting the dex reference limit:
>
> - Review your app's direct and transitive dependencies - Ensure any large library dependency you include in your app is used in a manner that outweighs the amount of code being added to the application. A common anti-pattern is to include a very large library because a few utility methods were useful. Reducing your app code dependencies can often help you avoid the dex reference limit.
> - Remove unused code with ProGuard - Configure the ProGuard settings for your app to run ProGuard and ensure you have shrinking enabled for release builds. Enabling shrinking ensures you are not shipping unused code with your APKs.
>
> Using these techniques can help you avoid the build configuration changes required to enable more method references in your app. These steps can also decrease the size of your APKs, which is particularly important for markets where bandwidth costs are high.

Answer (score 0):

Here i suggest two way may be help you.

1. Change in your `build.gradle` file

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false // Change Here
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
2. Go this path of your Computer(Windows Os) and change.

Path; `Controlpanel>System>Advance System Setting>Environment Variable`
this will open popup . Add or Change under `System Variable` on `PATH` and give it value `%SystemRoot%\system32`

May  be this will help you better

Comment: thank you, i use https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle